# How did this character survive?

Tags: alice-in-borderland

**Warning: This question contains massive spoilers about Alice in Borderland: Season 2. If you have not watched this season to the end yet, read on your own risk.**

The penultimate episode of season 2 shows the group's fight against the King of Spades. Multiple members of the team sustain serious injuries. Most notably, Ann is pretty definitely shown to have died, as she stops responding and lies on the ground, eyes emptily staring into the sky.

After these events, multiple hours pass (it gets dark) while Arisu and the Queen of Hearts play Croquet.

Once that game is cleared, the announcement says that all surviving players can choose between becoming permanent citizens of Borderland or returning to the real world. And indeed, during the TV announcement about the meteorite explosion, multiple players that have been shown to have died in Borderland are listed as deceased, such as Saori.

Yet, among the closing shots of the last episode, we see Ann being successfully revived in an ICU.

**How did Ann survive? She did not look like she was in a condition to answer "Decline" or "Accept" ...**